# Cargando la web de forma asíncrona pero sin URL

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

Estoy desarrollando una web para la gestión de pacientes.

La web tiene un solo punto de entrada (digamos que es **index.php**). Ese *landing* dibuja un cierto *HTML* que contiene un menú y un `div` de contenido.

Dependiendo del elemento del menú que es activado, se dispara una llamada por *Ajax* que llena el `div` de contenido.

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $.ajax({ url: "formulario.php", 
        dataType: 'text',
        success: function(data) {
            $("#sentences").html(data); 
        }, 
        error: function() {
            alert("error"); 
        }
    });
});
```

Como todo esto ocurre sin cambiar la *URL*, no tengo cómo definir una *URL* única para una sección en particular. Cualquier visitante que llegue al sitio verá simplemente el *landing* por defecto.

¿Hay alguna solución práctica para mantener el refresco dinámico del contenido, pero al mismo tiempo darle a cada sección una *URL* única?

Comment: no se entiende lo que preguntas. El contenido es dinámico pero desde la misma url pueden obtenerse varios contenidos? Mejor publica el código que tienes para entenderte mejor

Comment: La carga la hago asincrona con jquery y ajax cargo el contenido en un div de un html distonto y no es dinamico por el momento. Si te hace falta mas info puedo pasarte alguna captura

Comment: Y qué es lo que determina qué vas a cargar en ese div? Es algún parámetro o botón que gatilla esa carga? Me imagino que el contenido del div es distinto según distintas acciones. De otra manera, bastaría con compartir la url del navegador y el visitante siempre cargará (asíncronamente) el mismo contenido

Comment: @amenadiel Si el div lo uso para cargar contenido por ejemplo con un menu si le dan a pacientes cargaría una tabla con los distintos pacientes, y eso de compartir la url no lo acabo de entender

Comment: Ok, entonces tienes una sola URL de entrada, un index.php digamos, y dentro de ella vas cambiando de sección dependiendo de controles que no son links, por lo que la URL de la página no cambia

Comment: Ok, voy a redactar mejor tu pregunta a ver si es reabierta

Comment: Hola @sergibarca. Estoy votando para reabrir, pero se me ocurren 2 estrategias posibles: **1** enviar un parámetro al php, por ejemplo `formulario.php?seccion=menu1`, y modificar el código PHP para que sólo te devuelva lo que te interese... **2** recibir todo el HTML y trabajar desde JavaScript para procesarlo y sólo obtener el DIV que te interese... Sería bueno que aclares cuál de estas 2 estrategias te interesa implementar

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Usa almohadillas/*hash* (el símbolo `#`) para diferenciar cada sección de las demás. Así por ejemplo si tienes las secciones "formulario", "contacto", "historia", etc. Tendrían URLs únicas:

- index.php#formulario
- index.php#contacto
- index.php#historia

Y seguirías cargando tu menú de la misma manera a como lo estás haciendo ahora (o podrías cambiarlo para que fueran enlaces a #formulario, #contacto, etc. y detectar el cambio usando un controlador del evento [onhashchange](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/hashchange)).

Lo único sería que ahora los usuarios podrían acceder a una sección particular usando su "*deep link*". Entonces deberías cambiar un poco el código que se ejecuta al principio para que si hay un hash lo detecte y cargue la página correcta en lugar de la página por defecto. El cambio sería sencillo: leerías el hash (usando `window.location.hash`) y con un switch elegirías la url a cargar. Algo como esto:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    var myURL = "formulario.php";

    if (window.location.hash) {
       switch (window.location.hash) {
            case "#historia": myURL = "historia.php"; break;
            case "#contacto": myURL = "contacto.php"; break;
       }
    }

    $.ajax({ url: myURL, 
        dataType: 'text',
        success: function(data) {
            $("#sentences").html(data); 
        }, 
        error: function() {
            alert("error"); 
        }
    });
});
```

---

**Ejemplo funcionando**

Voy a hacer un ejemplo básico con 4 páginas (la principal y 3 subpáginas que se cargaran via AJAX). Dejo todo el código aquí, pero como no ejecuta PHP, he creado una [demo online](http://alvaromontoro.com/stackoverflow/55561/) en un servidor propio para que lo puedas ver funcionando.

index.php (página principal):

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Test Hash</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="opciones">
            <a href="#formulario">Formulario</a>
            <a href="#contacto">Contacto</a>
            <a href="#historia">Historia</a>
        </div>
        <div id="sentences"></div>

        <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.min.js"></script>
        <script>

            function hashChange() {

                var myURL = "formulario.php";

                if (window.location.hash) {
                    switch (window.location.hash) {
                        case "#contacto": myURL = "contacto.php"; break;
                        case "#historia": myURL = "historia.php"; break;
                        case "#formulario":
                        default: myURL = "formulario.php"; break;
                    }
                }

                $.ajax({ 
                    url: myURL,
                    dataType: 'text',
                    success: function(data) {
                        $("#sentences").html(data); 
                    }, 
                    error: function() {
                        alert("error"); 
                    }
                });
            }

            $(document).ready(function(){
                hashChange();
                $(window).on("hashchange", function() {
                    hashChange();
                });
            });
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

formulario.php:

```
<h1>Titulo Formulario</h1>
<p>Contenido formulario</p>
```

historia.php:

```
<h1>Historia</h1>
<p>Contenido Historia</p>
```

contacto.php:

```
<h1>Contacto</h1>
<p>Contenido Contacto</p>
```

Puedes ver que cuando se carga la página, se hará con el contenido de la sección indicada en el *hash* (si ninguno se especifica, se mostrará el formulario). Además, al cambiar la URL con cada interacción del menú, puedes pulsar los botones de adelante y atrás porque se guardarán los cambios en el historial del navegador.

Comment: @sergibarca: Esta es una buena solución que puede implementarse sin necesidad de aprender a usar un router como los que vienen en las librerías MVC o MVVM. Lo que sí faltó, Álvaro, es que al presionar un botón del menú debiese ir cambiando el hash, de lo contrario la navegación interna tendrá el mismo problema original.

Comment: Me parece buena solución, lo implemento y comento haber si funciona

Comment: Lo he implementado y no consigo hacerlo me cambia la url pero si hago refresh me continua saliendo la pagina principal no me carga el contenido en el div

Comment: @sergibarca ok. Deja lo miro y creo un ejemplo básico para mostrarte. Pero me tienes que dar un poco de tiempo que ahora ando algo liado

Comment: Muchas gracias :)

Comment: @sergibarca Me faltaba el `#` en los `case` del `switch` por eso no funcionaba. He actualizado el código de la respuesta y voy a poner un ejemplo que funciona (y si puedo lo subo a un servidor para que se pueda ver)

Comment: @AlvaroMontoro Funciona perfecto! Muchisimas gracias la verdad es que zanjado una duda muy grande!

Answer (score 3):

Se me ocurren unas cuántas formas, una es la que te dijo @AlvaroMontoro; otra es mediante la History API y otra es usando un router en la parte cliente.

#### History API

Esta API es muy práctica e intuitiva de usar. Tienes algunos métodos a disposición:

- `pushState`
- `replaceState`

El método que nos interesa más es `pushState`. Este método **añade una entrada** a la historia del navegador. Supongamos que haces click en *Home*, luego en *Portafolio* y por último en *Contáctame*, entonces, la pila de historia para tu dominio será:

- *Home* -> *Portafolio* -> *Contáctame*

Y si haces click en *atrás* del navegador seguirás ese orden en modo reverso.

> El método `pushState` **no comprueba si la URL o página que se le indica existe o no**. Este método solo la añade al stack de historia. Este método recibe tres parámetros: objeto de estado (para almacenar información respecto a la URL a cargar), el título del documento (ignorado por algunos navegadores) y la nueva URL (relativa) a mostrar.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  $('#menu a').on('click', function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var menuName = $(this).text();

    $.ajax({
      url: "formulario.php?page" + menuName,
      dataType: 'text',
    })
    .done(function (html) {
      $('#sentences').html(html);
      history.pushState(
        {},
        menuNames.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + string.slice(1),
        menuName
      );
    })
    .fail(function (xhr, status, error) {
      // hacer algo
    });
  });
});
```

El código anterior hace lo siguiente: cada vez que se haga click en un menú, se obtiene le HTML de la sección que indica el menú por medio del parámetro `?page` el cual se recibe en el backend y se envía una vista de acuerdo a ella. Finalmente, **actualiza** la URL de modo que si:

- Vas a *Home*: la URL será */tuapp/home*.
- Vas a *Portafolio*: la URL será */tuapp/portafolio*.
- Vas a *Contáctame*: la URL será *tuapp/contáctame*

---

#### Usando un Router del lado cliente

Tienes algunas opciones aquí, como [Page.js](https://github.com/visionmedia/page.js) y [Navigo](https://github.com/krasimir/navigo). Me gusta más Page.js porque se parece mucho al router de Vue.js. El mismo ejemplo que el anterior puede hacerse con Page.js:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  page.base('/app'); // nombre de tu app
  page('/home', render);
  page('/portafolio', render);
  page('/contactame', render);
  page(); // inicializa page.js
});

function render (ctx, next) {
  let pageName = ctx.pathname.split('/').reverse()[0];

  $.ajax({
    url: "formulario.php?page=" + pageName,
      dataType: 'text',
  })
  .done(function (html) {
    $('#sentences').html(html);
  })
  .fail(function (xhr, status, error) {
    // hacer algo
  });
});
```

En este caso, no es necesario prevenir las acciones por defecto de los links ya que de eso se encarga Page.js. Solo debes definir tu ruta base (`<base href="/tuapp/">`) y encargarte de traer el HTML e insertarlo en el documento.

**Demo**

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8"/>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0"/>
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge"/>
  <title>Demo Page.js</title>
  <base href="/app/">
</head>
<body>

  <a href="home">Home</a>
  <a href="portafolio">Portafolio</a>
  <a href="contactame">Contactame</a>
  
  <div id="view-router"></div>
  
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/page.js/1.7.1/page.min.js"></script>
  <script>
    document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function () {
      page.base('/app');
      page('/home', render);
      page('/portafolio', render);
      page('/contactame', render);
      page();
    });

    function render (ctx, next) {
      let viewRouter = document.getElementById('view-router');
      let pageName = ctx.pathname.split('/').reverse()[0];
      viewRouter.innerHTML = `Estás viendo ${pageName}`;
    }
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Sabía de Page.js pero nunca lo he utilizado. Trae esta librería alguna opción para navegar usando hashes al estilo de por ejemplo angular 2? p.e. `midominio.com/#/home/...`

Comment: @JoseHermosillaRodrigo Sí, solo debes pasarle `{ hashbang: true }` cuando inicializas page.

Comment: Me gustaría mucho saber en **qué se basa** la persona que me dió voto negativo y le dió positivo a Álvaro. Al menos *ten la decencia* de decirlo.